# Why Is There No Retain Cycle In ReceiveValue Block Combine Subscription

Tags: swiftui, combine, retain-cycle

I'm determined to fully understand why this isn't causing a reference cycle. And in general what is happening at each stage of memory management here.

I have the following setup:

```
struct PresenterView: View {
    @State private var isPresented = false
    var body: some View {
        Text("Show")
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                DataList()
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                isPresented = true
            }
    }
}

struct DataList: View {

    @StateObject private var viewModel = DataListViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(viewModel.itemViewModels, id: \.self) { itemViewModel in
                Text(itemViewModel.displayText)
            }.onAppear {
                viewModel.fetchData()
            }.navigationBarTitle("Items")
        }
    }
}

class DataListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    private let webService = WebService()

    @Published var itemViewModels = [ItemViewModel]()
    
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    func fetchData() {
        cancellable = webService.fetchData().sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in
            //...
        }, receiveValue: { dataContainer in
            self.itemViewModels = dataContainer.data.items.map { ItemViewModel($0) }
        })
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
    
}

final class WebService {
    
    var components: URLComponents {
        //...
        return components
    }

    func fetchData() -> AnyPublisher<DataContainer, Error> {
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: components.url!)
            .map { $0.data }
            .decode(type: DataContainer.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

So when I create a PresenterView and then dismiss it I get a successful deinit print.

However I don't understand why they is no reference cycle here. `DataListViewModel` has `cancellables` which has a subscription that captures self. So `DataListViewModel` -> subscription and subscription -> `DataListViewModel`. How can `deinit` be triggered? In general is there a good approach to understanding whether there is a retain cycle in these kinds of situation?

Comment: When does deinit happen? My guess is that it happens after the data has been receive (or otherwise, `dataTaskPublisher` is finished. So, the sink release its resources (e.g. the closures), so there's no more references that keep an instance of `DataListViewModel` in memory

Comment: Yes when data has been received. When you say releases resources it will store the closures weakly and set them to nil? Maybe this is outside of Combine and more general memory management. Would you be able to go into a bit more detail about that? Would it be that sink has reference to closure(s) which capture `DataListViewModel` - when the closure is set to nil/released it no longer points to `DataListViewModel` and that allows it to be deinitialised? I'm trying to picture each stage of the process. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the `.sink` subscriber holds references to the closures, until it receives a cancel or a completion. Then it sets them to `nil`. By way of testing, use `[weak self]` in the sink closure, and what you should see that `deinit` would happen before the data is received

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closure, as you expected, does retain a strong reference to `self`. The closure itself is maintained by the `Sink` subscriber.

If nothing else happens, this is a memory leak because the subscriber is never cancelled, because `AnyCancellable` is never released, because  `self` never de-inits, and `self` never de-inits because the subscriber is holding a reference it.

However, in your case, the publisher completes, and that's another way for the subscriber to release its closures. So, `self` is only released after the pipeline completes.

To illustrate, we can use a `PassthroughSubject` to explicitly send a completion:

```
class Foo {
   var c: AnyCancellable? = nil

   func fetch() {
      let subject = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()

      c = subject.sink {
         self.c // capture self
         print($0)
      }

      subject.send("sync")

      DispatchQueue.main.async { subject.send("async") }

      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) { 
         subject.send("async 2 sec")
         subject.send(completion: .finished)
      }
   }

   deinit { print("deinit") }
}


do {
   Foo().fetch()
}
```

Because `self` is captured, it's not released until after a completion is sent 2 seconds later:

```
sync
async
async 2 sec
deinit
```

If you comment out the line `subject.send(completion: .finished)`, there will not be a `deinit`:

```
sync
async
async 2 sec
```

If you use `[weak self]` in the closure, the pipeline would cancel:

```
sync
deinit
```